# Ubuntu software installation in air-gapped environments

Tags: apt, software-installation, custom-distributions, apt-mirror, custom-installer

Is there a recommended process for being able to install Ubuntu packages along their transitive dependencies, in an air-gapped IT environment having no direct Internet connectivity?

I can think of two challenges -

1. Bundling up each package of interest along its recursive set of dependencies, for delivery into the air-gapped environment
2. Setting up the target Ubuntu servers not to look for packages from the Internet but rather using the bundle from (1), or, setting up an internal download service which the target servers will reach out to instead of the Internet servers normally serving up packages

Your comments much appreciated!

Comment: Isn't jogdo (https://www.debian.org/CD/jigdo-cd/) what you want?

Answer (score 6):

Apt can use repositories on your local file system.

You would need to create the repo and know the packages you want to install on a computer with Internet access and apt-get.

```
apt-get -d install [packages]
mkdir /media/usb/MyRepo
cp -a /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /media/usb/MyRepo
dpkg-scanpackages /media/usb/MyRepo /dev/null > /media/usb/MyRepo/Packages
```

Now MyRepo can act as a repository. Transfer the directory to the system you need to install on such as on a USB drive. Then

```
echo "deb file:///media/usb/MyRepo ./" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/myrepo.list
apt-get update
apt-get install [packages]
```

There are other tools that you can install separately such as `apt-medium` for shared caches, `apt-mirror` for mirroring repos etc.

Comment: Wow this is really cool. I should accept the answer after I try it! so basically this delivers a repository with all of the packages I've chosen plus those required them, to the local machine, and then any such package can be installed on the local machine from that local repository, right?

Comment: Yep, It will use the packages from your repo so long as they are newer than other repos. Although I forgot to mention that this assumes the first machine has the same architecture as the second.

Comment: Of course. Do you mean architecture as in x86-64?

Comment: @matt yes like that and others. If you wanted to get i386 on an x86_64 machine you'd have to do `dpkg --add-architecture i386` then `apt-get update && apt-get -d install [package]:i386`

Answer (score 0):

## apt-offline

You can use [`apt-offline`](https://rickysarraf.github.io/apt-offline/) to install packages on an air-gapped host or to update/upgrade it. This tool is very handy, because it does not require the same Ubuntu version on both hosts (online/air-gapped).

### Prerequisites

1. Install `apt-offine` on your online host:

   ```
   sudo apt install apt-offline
   ```
2. Download `apt-offline` for your air-gapped host from:

   https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/all/apt-offline/download

   Make sure to replace `jammy` by the actual codename of your air-gapped host. You can query it with `lsb_release -c`.
3. Transfer the downloaded `apt-offline` package to your air-gapped host and install it:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i apt-offline_1.8.4-1_all.deb
   ```

### Update

To update the package lists on your air-gapped host:

1. Create a signature file for that task on your air-gapped host:

   ```
   sudo apt-offline set apt-offline.sig --update
   ```
2. Move that file to your online host and download the files for an offline update:

   ```
   apt-offline get apt-offline.sig --bundle bundle.zip
   ```
3. Move the bundle from your online host to your air-gapped host and install it:

   ```
   sudo apt-offline install bundle.zip
   ```

### Install packages

To install packages on your air-gapped host, just do the same as for updating, but create a signature file for installation instead. E. g. for packages `git` and `g++`:

```
sudo apt-offline set apt-offline.sig --install-packages git g++
```

After you imported the bundle on your air-gapped host, you can run `apt install` as usual:

```
sudo apt install git g++
```

### Upgrade

To upgrade your air-gapped host, just do the same as for updating, but create a signature file for upgrade instead:

```
sudo apt-offline set apt-offline.sig --upgrade
```

After you imported the bundle on your air-gapped host, you can run `apt upgrade` as usual:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```